# JQUery: selecting a value in a dynamically generated list of select options

Tags: jquery

I have the following:

1. A function which, based on user input, populates a `<select>` element with a set of `<option>` elements. The relevant code is:

   ```
   data = $.parseJSON(result);
   $.each(data, function (i, item)
   {
       $('div#step1 select#d-ward').append('<option value="' + item.id + '">' + item.ward + '</option>');
   });
   ```
2. A function which, based on other input, sets a given `<option>` in the `<select>` to be the currently displayed value. Relevant code:

   ```
   data = $.parseJSON(result);
   $('div#step1 select#d-ward').val(data.dis_ward);
   ```

Number 2 above is the problem, as it does not change the currently displayed value. I suspect this is due to the `<option>`s being dynamically generated, as the same code works if they are generated server-side instead.

What do I need to add in order to make sure the `<select>` is fully updated before I run the code above?

Comment: check the value of `data.dis_ward` by adding a `console.log(data.dis_ward)` before setting the value

Comment: Done so already, the data exists and has the expected value.

Comment: can you check the order of execution whether the set is executed before the options are appended... also hard code a value and check again

Comment: Yes, that is correct as well. The appends are done when the user provides a given set of inputs. It is not even possible to do the sets before that process has finished, as the users next input will depend on it.

Comment: if you try to set a hard coded value soon after the options are created what is happening

Comment: look at the demo.. [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/7wAka/1/)... it looks fine

Comment: Yea, it works when they are carried out in sequence. In this case, however, both steps are carried out in a separate function, so function 1 does the appending, exits, and after that function 2 is called, does the setting, and exits. If I instead copy both code snippets and run them in the same function, everything works...due to the architecture we are working with that is not an option however :-/

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42724/discussion-between-arun-p-johny-and-chrsva)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the clarification got from the comments/chats it turns out that loader and setter functions are async but they are called sequentially so when the setter gets called the options might not get called....

You need to make sure that the setter is called after the loader completes loading the option values... You can use a callback mechanism to do it.

Read more: [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call)